# C switch statement bug regular case and default hit

Tags: c, debugging, stack, switch-statement

I am currently writing my first program in C after being exposed to Java, and the purpose of this program is to simulate a stack that holds 10 integers. The user can ask to push ('u'), pop('o'), exit('x'), or change the format of output. There is a bug with how I am doing the outputs, but I can handle that later. The main cause for concern is that I get this output when running my program:

Welcome to the stack program.

Enter option: u
What number? 1
Stack: 1
Enter option: Invalid character.
Enter option: u
What number? 2
Stack: 1 2
Enter option: Invalid character.
Enter option: u
What number? 3
Stack: 1 2 3
Enter option: Invalid character.
Enter option:

As you can see, the program allows me to push items onto the stack and stores them (pop also works), but every time the user would be prompted to enter a new option the invalid character case is reached in my switch statement and creates an excess line in error. I understand more program context may be necessary, but is there anything glaringly wrong with my switch statement?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char currentOption;
int *printMode = 0;

//A program to simulate a stack data type of integers.
int main()
{
    printf("Welcome to the stack program.\n");
    printf("\nEnter option: ");
    scanf ("%c", &currentOption);

    while(currentOption != 'x')
    {
        processOption(currentOption);
        printf("\nEnter option: ");
        scanf ("%c", &currentOption);
    }
    return 0;
}

//interpret the user input character as one of several options
void processOption(char option)
{
    int storedValue;

    switch(option)
    {
        case 'u' : //push to stack
            printf("What number? ");
            scanf ("%d", &storedValue);
            if(push(storedValue) == 1)
            {
                printf("Overflow!!!");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Stack: ");
                printStack(printMode);
            }
            break;
        case 'o' : //pop, return popped value
            pop(&storedValue);
            if(storedValue == NULL)
            {
                printf("Underflow!!!");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Popped %d", storedValue);
                printf("\nStack: ");
                printStack(printMode);
            }
            break;
        case 'd' : //change print mode to decimal and print
            printf("\nStack: ");
            *printMode = 0;
            printStack(printMode);
            break;
        case 'h' : //change print mode to hex and print
            printf("\nStack: ");
            *printMode = 1;
            printStack(printMode);
            break;
        case 'c' : //change print mode to char and print
            printf("\nStack: ");
            *printMode = 2;
            printStack(printMode);
            break;
        case 'x' : //change print mode to char and print
            printf("Goodbye!");
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        default :
            printf("Invalid character." );
            break;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: show the `main()` function or the caller of `processOption()`

Comment: that 'els :' is a label statement and has nothing to do with the switch statement.  the correct format would be '  default:  ... break;

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Use the debugger (`gdb`). Read the documentation of every function that you are using. Use the return count from `scanf`

Comment: ^^thank you. I fixed this since it wasn't pertinent to my original issue and may distract from the "%c" problem, but thank you for the catch.

Answer (score 4):

In `main()` change :

```
scanf ("%c", &currentOption);
```

to

```
scanf (" %c", &currentOption);
```

The reason being the stray newline entered after the first input is immediately consumed by `scanf()` following it.
 To fix this use a blank space before the conversion specifier.
The blank space prefixed to `%c` tells `scanf()` to skip the first stray characters and consume only the character entered after that.

Comment: Thanks for the fix! Now that I've fixed that and my exit bug, it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

the main problem is:

The user enters a character by first typing the character, then hitting the 'return' key.

That  key (newline) is still in the buffer at the top of the next loop so is what is read.

That newline is part of the 'white space' definition.

To consume the white space, write the scanf like so:

```
scanf (" %c", &currentOption);
```

Notice the leading space in the format string?  A space in a format string causes white space to be consumed at that point in the input.

Also, the returned value from scanf(), and family of functions, should always be checked to assure the input/conversion operation was successful.

Comment: Thank you for your help! This was my problem. Also noticed I had a bug with the exit function. Hopefully I this type of error will not be an issue as I get a better understanding of the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think anything is wrong with your switch statement, but rather where you are acquiring

```
char option
```

It looks to me like you're doing something like

```
scanf("%c", &option);
processOption(option);
```

in a loop. When processOption() returns, scanf immediately picks up the newline that gets put into the stream when you press enter. \n, is, of course, not one of your valid options. So, change your scanf call to something like

```
scanf(" %c", &option);
```

This causes scanf to skip all leading whitespace, including newlines. This isn't required for scanf("%d", int) because whitespace is obviously not valid for a numeric value but *might* be valid for a char.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, even in JAVA scanner, if you scan for a numeric type like int, double, it reads until it hits an optional sign, then continutes until it hits a digit, then continues with digits, and for float/double one radix point, until something else is read, which it then puts back in the buffer (there is always room for 1, see man ungetc() ).  So the line feed is in the buffer waiting for the next scan input.  It's a classic case of the computer doing what you ask.  You can put a literal linefeed '\n' in the format to make scanf eat it, or add a dummy read of some sort, or read a line into a string/String/char[] and scan that with sscanf()/Scanner/>> !